# Spring boot validate only specific attributes using @valid in form

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my spring boot app. I have user class:

```
public class User {

   private Long id;

   @NotEmpty(message="Field is required.")
   @Size(max=50, message="Field cannot exceed 50 characters in length.")
   private String username;

   @NotEmpty(message="Field is required.")
   @Size(max=50, message="Field cannot exceed 50 characters in length.")
   private String name;

   @NotEmpty(message="Field is required.")
   @Email(message="Please enter valid email address.")
   private String email;

   .... getter and setter here....
}
```

I created user registration form where I am validating name, username and email.

Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/register", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String createUserForm(User user){
    return "user/create";
} 

@RequestMapping(value="/user/register", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult){

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "users/create";
    }
    //Here code to save user
    return "users/createdSuccess";

}
```

Now I wanted to create forgot the password page for users. Forget password page only contains email address. But If I use validate user model it always gives error as there is annotion to name and username attributes are added.

How I can ignore name and username annotation for forget password page and validate only email address.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account/forgot", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String forgotPassForm(User user){
    return "users/forgotPassword";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/account/forgot", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String resetPass(@Valid  User user, BindingResult bindingResult){

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "users/forgotPassword";
    }

    return "users/passwordEmailSent";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use @Validated-annotation with provided validation-group and appropriate validators. Here you see such examples :
http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-validation-example-mvc-validator

Comment: I change this :  public String resetPass(@ModelAttribute("email") @Validated User user, BindingResult bindingResult){ .... but getting error: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'email' available as request attribute

Comment: please look in the link, you should to add some dependencies and provide your custom validators

Comment: I don't want to create custom validation that is whole point of asking this question.

Comment: So, you can pass "forgot password"-case

Comment: what is forgot password case?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I'm understanding you right, but I kind of had a similar problem, where a *User* updates its credentials and there is of course the possibility, that the *password*-field ist empty (if the *User* doesn't want to (re) set it). So I simply check if the password field was empty or not (it may be a "dirty" solution, but in my case it worked (I additionally did a *form validation* on html-side)):

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
     // ignore field password
     if (!bindingResult.hasFieldErrors("password")) {
          // do something
     }
}
```